# Social Network Login Failure on Django, Callback url mismatched

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, github-api, django-allauth, github-oauth

I have problem for attaching social login.
I have tried google login on local, it was fine.
But when I try for deploy, Non-public domain is not supported.
I`m not sure  *.link is non-public domain, but it did not work for some reason.
So I am trying to do github login, but I have following errors..
There is callback URL mismatch, but I don't know which URL should I use.

Im using on Github this URL : **https://taeheejo.link/user/githubin/github/login/callback/**

urls.py

```
...
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('user/', include('authy.urls')),
path('sub/', include('tier.urls')),
...
```

authy/urls.py

```
...
path('login/', authViews.LoginView.as_view(template_name='registration/login.html'), name='login'),
path('githubin/', include('allauth.urls')),
...
```

And Here is an Error..

[image]

I have added on admin pannel sitename and application too..

Can someone please tell me which part am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I was suffering from this issue, at the end I found that I was missing redirect urls from my developer account.
These are some key points to do it correctly:
Make sure you have added correct `redirect and logout url`. And then make sure you have added `CLIENT SECRET and API KEY` correctly in django-admin panel.And don't forget to add **sites** from django-admin panel.